# Relatively positioned element stays fixed even when page scrolled down in IE7

Tags: internet-explorer-7, css-position

I have this absolutely positioned icon `<a>`, hence its parent `<li>` is relatively positioned. The list items are in a scrollable `<div>`.

Problem is except for these `<li>s` other elements in the div are scrolling along with the height of the div, whereas the `<li>s` stays fixed whereas I expected the `<li>s` also to be scrolled along inside the div.

Tried overflow:hidden, zoom:1, doesn't work.

Here is the [jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/code_tweetie/57vpy/1/show/)

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer from this question, https://stackoverflow.com/a/13996983/1531426

I thought I searched enough :(

Adding `position:relative;overflow:auto;` to the container div which has the height, fixes the issue.